# How can I protect a MOSFET from high voltage spikes in a DCDC converter?

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, mosfet-driver

I built DCDC converter using TL494 that is able to step down 30-200V to 12V with reasonable output.  The circuit worked fine for quite a while, but I have always tested it while slowly raising the voltage from 100 -> 190V.

Unfortunately it failed once I just started with 190V right away. MOSFET Q5 died pretty much immediately and took with the driver and the TL494 with it. I suspect it turned on by itself and died.

After measuring it was dead short on all legs in any direction. The driver also died and then the TL494 smoked.

Here is the schematic:

[image]

What can I do to prevent that from happening? Would a simple Zener clamp circuit be good?

Something like this?

[image]

Comment: Do you suspect it is VDS breakdown? or Switch node breakdown of the driver? You'd normally go on to scope some still-working converter to identify the problem before attempting solutions. I doubt it has to do with overcurrent or overload, because such damage would be visible and usually smoky.

Comment: @tobalt unfortunately i do not know what happened, after replacing fuse i tried it again and by that time pretty much all ICs were dead. I don't have another piece to test it but perhaps because of HV mosfet turned itself on.

Comment: Zenner between gate and stock always used.

Comment: Please change image to white background - much more readable. I have changed gey to black which helps visually, but white will be much n=better.

Comment: AS USER263983 SAYS - place a reverse biased zener between Q5 gate and source - physically & electrically close to FET. V_FET slightly above Cdrive_max. This clamps voltage peaks coupled drain to gate. by Miller capacitance.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I edited main post, zener I have chosen is for 15V, is that correct?

Comment: @Kaminari - yes - zener as shown. Vzener not much above drive voltage - whatever the driver produces. [I had a system that would die in minutes without a zener and that never failed when a zener was added. I've always used them ever since, regardless of load type.

Comment: For 190 V input, you need at least 300 V rating on your MOSFET to make it a viable design. Please post oscillograms of Vds over your MOSFET.

Comment: What else is connected to `BATT+`, is that all the bypass in the entire circuit (C7, C9)?  What type are C7/C9? Is the 12V output guaranteed low during startup, and does it have a minimum load? Have you considered current mode control at all?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the FET shown on the diagram is what you are using.
If not, you should at least say so in the text and ideally change the diagram.

Regardless of the specific failure reason, you are running the FET shown within a tenth of an inch* (2.5mm) of its life. It is rated at 200 V

Running a 200V FET at 200V (or 190V) even in a buck converter is dicing with disaster.

[irfr13n20dpbf](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfr13n20dpbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153562d59d9205f) datasheet.

Also, the FET is not a good one. Rdson is 135 milliOhms - there are much better ones available.

---

As USER263983 says - place a reverse biased zener between Q5 gate and source - physically & electrically close to FET. V_Zener should be slightly above Cdrive_max. This clamps voltage peaks coupled drain to gate by Miller capacitance.

Comment: I did test it on 190V slowly however this DCDC converter is meant to run at max 40s battery which is 168V, I think at this voltage it should be fine this mosfet?

Comment: @Kaminari What you are saying is unclear. You mention testing on 190V. Was that really 40s=168V or a different voltage source. || If you have destroyed all your FETs I would certainly change to a better one if at all possible. Higher Vds, lower Rdson. ... .|| Still marginal at 168V. Unless you can be certain of minimal spikes and ringing you are at risk.  || A zener in parallel with D2 (or faster surge suppressor) and maybe some fom of snubber may help. BUT higher Vds FET would be a first step.

Answer (score 0):

So,

- Starting from 100V, then increasing to 190V: it works
- Starting from 190V: it burns.

As Russel says, the FET is not well chosen for this application, max Vds is too low and RdsON is too high, but I don't think this is why it dies. If it dies from excessive Vds, it would do so in both cases.

Starting from a high voltage into discharged output caps means inductor current will rise very quickly:

\$ \frac{di}{dt} = \frac{V}{L} = \frac{200V}{100µH} = 2A/µs\$

OK. What's the current limit on that FET driver...

[image]

Worst case 2.1V, there's a 1k:10k voltage divider which means to get 2.1V on the driver's current sense input we need 11/10*2.1=2.31V across the FET RdsON. Datasheet specifies a maximum of 235mOhm RdsON but no typical, it could actually be lower, so let's say the current limiter trips at Id=10-12A, which is alright.

The driver's datasheet specs "CS shutdown propagation delay 65-360 ns" ; your MOSFET doesn't have a large gate charge so let's go with the middle of this range, say 200ns. So, inductor current increases by 0.4A before it turns off.

We're doing startup so the output caps are discharged. Your TL494 runs at 215kHz which means a period of T=4.6µs. During this time, voltage across the inductor will be about one diode drop plus voltage drop due to ESR, say 2 volts total, so inductor current drops only by less than 100mA.

Thus on the next cycle the driver is told to turn on while the FET is already in overcurrent condition.

[image]

It sits around waiting during the blanking time (say 750ns) then detects the overcurrent and turns it off, which takes 65-360ns, let's round that up to 900ns total before the FET turns off. So during that time, inductor current increased by 1.8A.

So on each cycle, inductor current increases by 1.8A, then decreases by 0.1A, for a total of 1.7A.

This keeps going until the FET melts down.

It doesn't burn at 100V input because the lower input voltage causes inductor current to rise twice as slow. It still probably rises to unsafe levels, and I'd bet the FET would burn if you had much higher capacitance on the output.

It will also burn in case of shorted output, and probably on output overcurrent too.

[image]

This driver has a FAULT output. You should use that to make the TL494 back off for a few cycles in case of overcurrent. Ideally the back off delay should depend on output voltage, basically it should allow the inductor current to fall to safe levels so it doesn't run away when output voltage is zero.

A variable frequency constant ON-time converter with current sensing in the diode (not the MOSFET) would probably be safer. You'd lose some efficiency due to the sensing resistance being in the current path almost all the time, but it's on the low side so you can use a low value resistor to reduce the power wasted and an opamp to amplify the signal.

Comment: You are probably correct why that happened however i will be honest with you, Im not that good with analog electronics to implement fixes you proposed, do you have more info/example circuit? Would zener diode not suffice?

Comment: I have never used TL494 so I have no idea how to actually configure it to do this. But, your real problem is your in/out voltage ratio is really too high for a buck converter. A transformer based topology would be a better choice. In fact most off the shelf universal input AC-DC switching power supplies will also happily work on DC, so you may find one compatible with your voltage range. Also they're isolated, which is much safer: in your case if the 12V stuff can be touched by the user, a shorted MOSFET would result in high voltage on the output which would be dangerous.

Comment: TI webench recommends a [flyback design](https://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=202335EE648AB48E) but this would need a custom transformer. If you search in the [AC-DC switching supplies](https://www.mouser.fr/c/power/power-supplies/switching-power-supplies) you can find some that will run on DC for example [this one](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/CUI-Inc/VOF-65C-S12?qs=Cb2nCFKsA8qEhg7jv4uhCA%3D%3D), readymade, no effort needed! (but its 100V minimum voltage may be a little too high).

Comment: Some suitable candidates also in the [Isolated DC-DC](https://www.mouser.fr/c/power/dc-dc-converters/isolated-dc-dc-converters/) category if you filter by min/max input voltage.

Comment: Unfortunately due to size constraints flyback with transformer is not an option, I had one built on LT8316 and worked decently but it was just too big. How about changing mosfet to for example IRFS4227TRLPBF ? Plus adding that zener.

Comment: 200V for 190V is still on the razor's edge... anyway the problem you need to fix is how it's controlled, without that the new MOSFET will also take a huge overcurrent at startup.

Comment: Its not designed for 190V, it was just my initial tests, max supported voltage is 168V. So how can i fix how its controlled? I didnt see any obvious issues with ltspice

Comment: Ah OK for 168V a 200V MOSFET should be alright. I think you could mess with the dead time of TL494 to remove cycles when the driver's FAULT output trips.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151664/discussion-between-kaminari-and-bobflux).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to other answers (without repeating what they say), I believe implementing a soft-start feature would be beneficial. The [TL494 data sheets](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tl494-d.pdf) shows how this can be done: -

[image]

You might also choose to add a small capacitor (maybe 47 pF) across the top resistor (R20) in the feedback potential divider to curtail the PWM on power up thus preventing bigger peak currents into the inductor when the output capacitors are initially starting to be charged from full discharge state. Other stuff: -

- Check the reverse voltage rating of the flyback diode (D2). I can't figure out what part number it has so I can't double check this part.
- The 13 volt Zener (D5) might be problematic on transient situations. It's meant to clamp the output voltage but, it's sailing a little close to becoming destroyed should a significant overshoot occur. You have also missed a "J" from the part number so it took a little while to find. It's important to get the details right.

Comment: Soft start is probably a bad idea because bootstrap circuit cannot handle outputting 10-12V for more than couple of milliseconds.

Comment: @Kaminari you can always increase the value of the BS capacitor. Anyway, soft-start ensures that the duty cycle is kept particularly low initially. It doesn't mean there will be no PWM pulses. Please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I made this thing. It's a low voltage buck chip with a cascode. It's a bit unconventional, because it's somewhat upside down.

[image]

How it works:

Q5 is the power-on switch. When it receives base current (here it is biased with 3V3) it acts as a current source (570µA). This biases Zener D1 and creates (via Q1) a floating 12V supply hanging below the high voltage rail. Q6 protects Q1 from SOA violation when charging decoupling cap C1. This slows down startup to a few tens of milliseconds, so R6 should be set to zero to speed up simulation.

D3 shifts voltage on the chip's UVLO to delay startup until there's enough supply voltage for a solid turn-on of the cascode MOSFET, you may use a voltage divider instead if the chip has an accurate threshold UVLO pin.

Now the chip is a standard synchronous buck so it has an output and also, of course, feedback. Pretty much any integrated buck chip should work as long as:

- It's synchronous
- Input voltage > 12V
- Frequency < 200kHz
- Does not sense current on the bottom FET, only the top

I used this one because it fits the bill and has a model in LTspice.

The trick is PMOS cascode M1 which translates the output to ground level. When the chip outputs a "high" level (internal top FET ON) the PMOS conducts. When it outputs a "low" level (internal bottom FET ON) the PMOS does not conduct. So the buck chip acts as a MOSFET driver, and drives it through its source.

An advantage is that all the current goes through the chip's internal top FET, so its current sensing capabilities are still working, like cycle by cycle current limiting, etc.

The chip's internal bottom FET is used to drive the cascode FET and turn it off quickly, which is why a synchronous buck chip is needed. But the inductor current does not go through the internal bottom FET (only the top one), so a buck chip that senses current on the bottom FET will not work.

After this we have the usual buck stuff (diode, inductor, cap).

Q4 and the current mirror on top transport the feedback voltage from ground level up to the chip. It's the normal feedback current divider and RC compensation (R9,C6)... but split in half, with the current mirror voltage shifter in the middle. Output voltage will be shifted by one Vbe, which could be corrected with a more complicated circuit.

One drawback is the chip can't sense input voltage, so its slope compensation may not work. So it would be better to use a chip that doesn't rely too much on that.

Shopping for M1: 200V PMOS (rare) with reasonable RdsON and not too high gate charge... [SQJ431EP](https://www.digikey.fr/en/products/detail/vishay-siliconix/SQJ431EP-T1-GE3/6595013), [IXTA26P20P)(https://www.digikey.fr/en/products/detail/ixys/IXTA26P20P-TRL/11206258).

You can use your choice of high voltage small signal BJTs, I used those just because LTSpice has a model.

To keep the chip alive, inductor value should be scaled according to voltage. For example if the chip can run on 30V with a 10µH inductor, we can assume its cycle by cycle current limit is fast enough for that di/dt, so if you multiply the voltage by 6, also multiply the inductor by 6 to keep the same di/dt. 100µH should be fine. As always the inductor saturation current should be above the current limit threshold.

[Link to schematic.](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ct7kn8nf5bea2ikpn656y/pwmdcdc_cascode.asc?rlkey=3en1bubilv4x1jssxnm59zn7e&dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

The thing all the other answers are missing is that in fact the circuit kaminaris has shown is not wired up like in the gate driver data sheet, it is missing a Diode and therefore has no knowledge of the voltage across the MOSFET drain to source.

It therefore has absolutely no concept of current whatsoever and it's totally unable to regulate itself.

A higher voltage will generate a much more aggressive inrush than a lower one and gradually ramping up.

Kind of like bobflux' answer except without any ability to turn off until the output voltage is higher than the feedback threshold.